# What is the correct way to find the image of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $x$ axis and $y$ axis in $R^2$ are rotated counterclockwise by $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$ to yield new $x'$ and $y'$ axes. Then find the new coordinates of the point $(1,3)$

I know the rotation matrix in $R^2$ is given by:

\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta 
\end{pmatrix}

Replacing $\theta$ by  $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$ . I get the required matrix as:

\begin{pmatrix} 
\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2} & \dfrac{-1}{2}  \\
 \dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}
\end{pmatrix}

Now my main problem is that how should I multiply the point $(2,1)$ with given matrix. ie should I consider $(2,1)$ as a 1 x 2 matrix or consider it $(2,1)^T$ that is a 2x1 matrix.

In both cases I am getting different answers, and in my book answer is given by considering it 1 x 2 matrix.

Can anyone tell what convention should I follow when solving these kind of problems.

Comment: If you know that this is what a rotation matrix looks like, then I would think that you should also know whether you’re working with row or column vectors. The rotation matrix for one of these doesn’t look quite like what you’ve got in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You write that you "know the rotation matrix in $R^2$ is given by" this:

\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta 
\end{pmatrix}

The question is whether one should rotate by multiplying with the matrix on the right
$$(x \,\, y)\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
or instead by multiplying with the matrix on the left
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta 
\end{pmatrix} 
(x \, \, y)^T
= \begin{pmatrix} 
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
x  \\
y
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
Well, you can figure this out by testing with a simple example. Imagine that you have the unit vector in the $x$ direction, given by $(1 \,\, 0)$. You rotate it by $\theta = \pi/2$ (in the counterclockwise direction, of course), and you get the unit vector in the $y$ direction, given by $(0 \,\, 1)$. Plug $\pi/2$ into the matrix and you get
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Multiplying with the matrix on the right gives
$$(1 \, \, 0) \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = (0 \,\, -1)
$$
That's not correct.

Multiplying with the matrix on the left gives
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
That's correct!

So multiplying with the matrix on the left it is!

Answer (score 0):

Every linear transformation $T$ has associated a matrix $A$ such that: 
$$T(u)=A\cdot u$$

Lets try with a simple example:

$\begin{pmatrix} 
\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2} & \dfrac{-1}{2}  \\
 \dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}
\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{\sqrt3}{2} \\ \dfrac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}$

So you have to multiply

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2} & \dfrac{-1}{2}  \\
 \dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}
\end{pmatrix}(a,b)^\intercal$$